# Não estou conseguindo resolver esse erro de sintax,não estou conseguindo identificar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sintaxe

```
class Sale < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :discount
  has_many :product_quantities
  has_one :comission

  after_save do
    calc = 0
    # Soma o preço dos produtos vezes a quantidade deles
    self.product_quantities.each {|p| calc += p.product.price * p.quantity}
    # Verifica se existe um desconto e aplica caso exista
      if self.discount.kind == "porcent"
        calc -= calc / self.discount.value
      elsif self.discount.kind == "money"
        calc -= self.discount.value
      end

    # Verifica se já existe uma comissão, caso sim atualiza, caso não cria uma nova.
    if self.comission.present?
      self.comission.update(value: (calc * 0.1), status: :pending)
    else
      Comission.create(value: (calc * 0.1), user: self.user, sale: self, status: :pending)
    end
  end

end
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este bloco de código abaixo está indentado desnecessariamente:

```
  if self.discount.kind == "porcent"
    calc -= calc / self.discount.value
  elsif self.discount.kind == "money"
    calc -= self.discount.value
  end
```

Código corrigido:

```
class Sale < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :discount
  has_many :product_quantities
  has_one :comission

  after_save do
    calc = 0
    # Soma o preço dos produtos vezes a quantidade deles
    self.product_quantities.each {|p| calc += p.product.price * p.quantity}
    # Verifica se existe um desconto e aplica caso exista
    if self.discount.kind == "porcent"
      calc -= calc / self.discount.value
    elsif self.discount.kind == "money"
      calc -= self.discount.value
    end

    # Verifica se já existe uma comissão, caso sim atualiza, caso não cria uma nova.
    if self.comission.present?
      self.comission.update(value: (calc * 0.1), status: :pending)
    else
      Comission.create(value: (calc * 0.1), user: self.user, sale: self, status: :pending)
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: muito obrigado pelo feedback vou testar!